FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in next js production level
Our team has built a Next.js app. It works fine in local production mode, but after deployment to production, it eventually encounters the following error:
Our next js version:14.2.3
yarn version:1.22.19
Node version: 20.12.2

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 0xb86ecf node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [next-server (v14.2.3)]
 2: 0xef74d0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [next-server (v14.2.3)]
 3: 0xef77b7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [next-server (v14.2.3)]
 4: 0x1109355  [next-server (v14.2.3)]
 5: 0x11098e4 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [next-server (v14.2.3)]
 6: 0x11207d4 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, char const*) [next-server (v14.2.3)]
 7: 0x1120fec v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [next-server (v14.2.3)]
 8: 0x1179dac v8::internal::MinorGCJob::Task::RunInternal() [next-server (v14.2.3)]
 9: 0xd3f5a6  [next-server (v14.2.3)]
10: 0xd42b4f node::PerIsolatePlatformData::FlushForegroundTasksInternal() [next-server (v14.2.3)]
11: 0x18b8913  [next-server (v14.2.3)]
12: 0x18cd38b  [next-server (v14.2.3)]
13: 0x18b9637 uv_run [next-server (v14.2.3)]
14: 0xbcdbe6 node::SpinEventLoopInternal(node::Environment*) [next-server (v14.2.3)]
15: 0xd13054  [next-server (v14.2.3)]
16: 0xd13aed node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [next-server (v14.2.3)]
17: 0xc77dbf node::Start(int, char**) [next-server (v14.2.3)]
18: 0x7f10687ddd90  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
19: 0x7f10687dde40 __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
20: 0xbcae3e _start [next-server (v14.2.3)]
Aborted (core dumped)
error Command failed with exit code 134.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 134.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

We have tried by increasing the ram size of node but it was not effective.
